# Transfer (in app) purchase to new app

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

Is there any official way (=accepted by Apple) to transfer/apply In App Purchases from one app to another (within the same dev account)?

The freemium app **MyApp1** has been in the iOS App Store for several years. Now I would like to release a completely redesigned version **MyApp2** **as new app**: Users who do not want to update can continue using MyApp1 without accidentally downloading the update (since its not an update but a new app) and MyApp1 can still be provides with some updates/fixes.

But users who already bough MyApp1 should now be able to transfer (some of) their IAPs to MyApp2, or to get some discount when purchasing an IAP in MyApp2. Is that possible?

Is it allowed to use **custom URL scheme` to do this?

- In default mode MyApp2 only provides IAP `feature1` for $5
- MyApp1 provides the same IAP. If the user has bought the IAP item, the app offers a feature to call MyApp2 using a custom URL scheme
- If MyApp2 is called by the custom URL scheme, it "knows" that the feature was purchased in MayApp1 and offers the IAP `feature1_discounted` for $1, which was hidden before

Of course this workflow is not bullet proof and someone could easily send fake information about the purchase to MyApp2 by using the custom URL scheme. One could make the process more secure by adding some secrete/authentication, but (at least in my case) the process does not need to be absolutely secure: The worst  thing that could happen is, that I get a new customer for $1 instead of $5, but at least I get a new customer...

So the question is **not** if it works (it does), **but if this process will be accepted by Apple.**

Comment: Hey Andrei, could I ask how did it go for you? I am trying to do the same thing (although with different method instead of `custom URL scheme`.) Did Apple pose any problem with your approach?

Comment: I eventually dropped the project since it was impossible to get any reliable information from Apple. I tried to contact the Store support several times but got no useful information back. The truth with the App Store is: No one can tell you the rules. It all depends on wether the guy at Review has a good or bad day. You can use this approach and everything works fine for years and all of the sudden Apple removes your app from the store. Something which is fine today can be a big problem tomorrow. This sucks for users but this just the way the awesome, shiny Apple World works.

Comment: Thank you for sharing :) It is quite unfortunate that the developers are at the mercy of the App Store in this situation. If I ever get to try this I'll make sure to leave my experience as well. 

Hope you have a great day :)

Comment: You are very welcome! Would be great to hear if that worked out for you. All the best!